# can not download data from google trends with gtrendsR

Tags: r, google-trends

I just installed the package `gtrendsR` and tried basic functions I found in the documenation like `gtrends("NHL", geo = c("CA", "US"))`. Every time I received the same error message:

> Error in get_widget(comparison_item, category, gprop, hl) : 
>     widget$status_code == 200 is not TRUE

What is my mistake?

Comment: See the note on the [github page](https://github.com/PMassicotte/gtrendsR): "Due to recent changes to Google Trends API, the CRAN version of the package is no longer working. If you wan to continue to query Google Trends, you have to install the development version of the package. This will be soon deployed on CRAN." What version are you running? The CRAN version or the github development version?

Comment: thanks. I am running the CRAN version